# How to save a complete page in Chrome using JavaScript (from Dev Tools)?

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome, to save a complete web page I can click Ctrl+S > "Format: Web page, Single File" > save it as ".mhtml".

How can I do the same thing but automatically, using JavaScript?

If I open the chrome devtools, is there a line of javascript I can enter that will accomplish that?

Comment: How would that be any more automatic than CTRL + S?

Comment: [chrome.pageCapture](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/pageCapture/)

Answer (score 0):

just give this pice of code into your console (Chrome Dev Tools) and the popup where to save (The webpage will be saved as an HTML file in your default download location) will open

```
(async () => {
  const html = await fetch(window.location.href).then(response => response.text());
  const blob = new Blob([html], { type: 'text/html' });
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.style.display = 'none';
  a.href = url;
  a.download = 'page.html';
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }, 100);
})();
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: its self explained i think and it answer the question.

Comment: Doesn't work for .mhtml    :    Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: mhtml is not defined
    at <anonymous>:3:26